# Access key values of dictionary with tuple as key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary `dict` like this, with tuples as keys:

```
 dict = { (1, 1): 10, (2,1): 12}
```

and tried to access it like this :

```
new_dict = {}
for key, value in dict: 
    new_dict["A"] = key[0]
    new_dict["B"] = key[1]
    new_dict["C"] = value
```

But it fails, since `key` does not seem to resolves to a tuple. What is the correct way?

Comment: You can try `for key, value in dict.items():` if you are using Python 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To iterate over key value pairs, use the `.items()` method of the dict.

Also, give the dictionary a name like `my_dict` to avoid overwriting the builtin `dict`.

```py
new_dict = {}
for key, value in my_dict.items(): 
    new_dict["A"] = key[0]
    new_dict["B"] = key[1]
    new_dict["C"] = value
```